# Pass environment variables to Hive Transform or MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to pass a custom environment variable to an executable (my-mapper.script in the example below) used in a Hive Transform
eg:

```
SELECT
   TRANSFORM(x, y, z)
   USING 'my-mapper.script'
FROM
(
   SELECT
      x, y, z
   FROM
      table
)
```

I know in Hadoop streaming this can be achieved using

```
-cmdenv EXAMPLE_DIR=/home/example/dictionaries/
```

But I do not know how to do this in a Hive Transform/MapReduce.

Any ideas?

Comment: yep good generic question
some python example are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727401/how-to-pass-parameters-to-python-streaming-script-in-hive?noredirect=1#comment24097093_16727401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your script with a simple 2 line bash script to setup the environment. e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
export FOO=boo
my-mapper.script
```

And then use this script in the query

```
USING 'wrapper.sh'
```

my-mapper.script will see **FOO** (with value "boo") in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
% hive -hiveconf CURRENT_DATE='2012-09-16' -f test.hql
```

Comment: No, that just passes a variable to the .hql script. I want to pass it to inside the map reduce executable.