# How to pass parameters to Python streaming script in Hive?

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming, hive

Hive user can stream table through script to transform that data:

```
ADD FILE replace-nan-with-zeros.py;

SELECT
  TRANSFORM (...)
  USING 'python replace-nan-with-zeros.py'
  AS (...)
FROM some_table;
```

I have a simple Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys


kFirstColumns= 7

def main(argv):

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip();
        inputs = line.split('\t')

        # replace NaNs with zeros
        outputs = [ ]
        columnIndex = 1;
        for value in inputs:
            newValue = value
            if columnIndex > kFirstColumns:
                newValue = value.replace('NaN','0.0')
            outputs.append(newValue)
            columnIndex = columnIndex + 1

        print '\t'.join(outputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**How to make *kFirstColumns* to be a command-line or some other kind of parameter to this Python script?**

Thank you!

Comment: I asked the same question (but for a generic way, not just python), here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339123/pass-environment-variables-to-hive-transform-or-mapreduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is really trivial. Use

```
ADD FILE replace-nan-with-zeros.py;

SELECT
  TRANSFORM (...)
  USING 'python replace-nan-with-zeros.py 7'
  AS (...)
FROM some_table;
```

instead of just

```
  ...
  USING 'python replace-nan-with-zeros.py'
  ...
```

It works fine for me.

Python script should be changed to:

```
kFirstColumns= int(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are already sort of doing it.

You are grabbing `sys.argv[1:]` and passing it to main, but not using the arguments.  What I would suggest (easiest route wise) would be to change your script as follows:

```
def main(kFirstColumns):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Then run your script like

```
$ python myScript.py 7
```

Then, you can look at [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) when you want to do more complicated command line options.

Comment: your answer is useful but for a those who look how to access command line options from Python
my problem was to pass those parameters from Hive

Comment: see my answer to find out what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but you could pass the parameter by including it as an additional column in your query.

```
SELECT
  TRANSFORM (...)
  USING 'python replace-nan-with-zeros.py'
  AS (...)
FROM (SELECT 7 AS kFirstColumns, * FROM some_table);
```

Then, when you parse the row in your script, the first column value will be the parameter you are looking for. Simply pop it into your local variable to remove it from the list of column values.

```
line = line.strip();
inputs = line.split('\t')
kFirstColumns = inputs.pop(0)
```

Hope that helps.